Сan’t change a service startup type after adding triggers
After I add SERVICE_TRIGGER with type SERVICE_TRIGGER_TYPE_DEVICE_INTERFACE_ARRIVAL to start a service using WinAPI, I can't change the service startup type by ChangeServiceConfig(A/W). Without changing the trigger type to SERVICE_DISABLE before adding trigger, trying to add a trigger always fails with an error ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.
Below is the simplified code I use to add a trigger to start a service. An attempt to change the startup type to SERVICE_DEMAND_START always ends with an error (regardless of the selected type, the function will always fail with an error ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (ErrorCode 871)).
The following code is executed after a successful call to CreateService(...) and reopening of the required SC_HANDLER
{
// Some code...
}

auto __service = CreateService(__hSCManager,serviceName,serviceName,SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,
        SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
        SERVICE_DEMAND_START,
        SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,
        __servicePath,
        NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL); // Succes

{
// Some code...
}

auto __hSCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
if (__hSCManager)
{
    auto __hService = OpenService(__hSCManager, SERVICE_NAME, SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG);
    if (__hService)
    {
        if (ChangeServiceConfig(__hService,
            SERVICE_NO_CHANGE,SERVICE_DISABLED,SERVICE_NO_CHANGE,
            NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL))
        {  
            SERVICE_TRIGGER_SPECIFIC_DATA_ITEM __item;
            {
            // Fill item  
            }

            SERVICE_TRIGGER __trigger;

            __trigger.dwTriggerType     = SERVICE_TRIGGER_TYPE_DEVICE_INTERFACE_ARRIVAL;
            __trigger.dwAction          = SERVICE_TRIGGER_ACTION_SERVICE_START;
            __trigger.pTriggerSubtype   = const_cast<GUID*>(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE);
            __trigger.cDataItems        = 1;
            __trigger.pDataItems        = &__item;

            SERVICE_TRIGGER_INFO __info;
            __info.cTriggers = 1;
            __info.pTriggers = &__trigger;
            __info.pReserved = NULL;

            if(ChangeServiceConfig2(__hService,SERVICE_CONFIG_TRIGGER_INFO,&__info)==0) 
            {
                // !!!!!!
                if (ChangeServiceConfig(__hService,SERVICE_NO_CHANGE,
                                        SERVICE_DEMAND_START,
                                        ERVICE_NO_CHANGE,
                                        NULL,NULL,NULL,
                                        NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) == 0)
                {
                    // !!! Will never reach !!!
                }    
            }
        }
    }
}

Triggers are added (this can be seen using the SC utility) but the service cannot be moved out of the SERVICE_DISABLE state either using the SC utility or using the window service manager, or using the WinAPI fncs.
As I found out, triggers cannot be added without switching the service to the SERVICE_DISABLE state.
My question is:
How to change service startup state after adding triggers?
Or maybe I'm wrong in the sequence when adding triggers?
Microsoft documentation is very sparse on this topic.

Everything is simpler than it turned out. During the filling process, SERVICE_TRIGGER_SPECIFIC_DATA_ITEM::cbData (item size) was specified incorrectly - I took the number of wchar_t characters of the string and not the size of the string in bytes.
After specifying the correct line size, everything works as intended.
